# Japanese, Russian or English characters in dynamic Text Field for PDF

Tags: pdf, unicode, character-encoding, jasper-reports

Perhaps someone could help me : I've got a problem with my project. I've got a dynamic pdf report, generated by Jasper, which contains dynamic TextField in Japanese, Russian or English text, and could be in Bold, Itallic or Normal Font. This report is generated in a multi- language application, but I've no way to know in which language the input text has been originally written.
I try to use the font delivered by Microsoft ARIAUNI.TTF, but the problem is that this font doesn't work with bold or italic Japanese characters.
I've got some solutions (like remove all bold or italic TextField in my jrxml file), but I don't find it an ideal solution.

Has anyone had ever such a problem ? Does someone have a good solution for it?

Thanks in advance,

Matthieu Blanchard

Comment: What other fonts have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

We use the "Arial MS" font for Japanese characters specifically. Works nice for us.

Comment: Thanks Todd. That's what I've done : used Arial MS font specially for Japanes characters.